# Custom form in shopify

Tags: custom-controls, shopify, custom-tools

I am currently researching Shopify. My website is going to be a simple E-commerce shopping website as any other except there is requirement where the user should be allowed to customize the product.

Lets take a candle for instance. And lets consider this site caters to custom made candles where the user has option to choose the

- wax color (there is multi-color option in here, and user should be allowed to choose the area to be colored with the respective color)
- the embellishments if any needed on the candle
- say if they want a particular pattern on the candle ...
- description box and so on ... you get the idea

I did get an option 'Built-in Tools'. But i couldn't find an option for Custom Tool. 
This may sound odd but, Can i create a custom tool using custom apps and then integrate it.

Can anyone direct me to site that gives me some insight on this. As i am very new to Shopify.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Pirate-eir, you'll either need an app, or, need to make some changes to your shopify theme to get this working. Shopify does allow line item properties https://docs.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products - however, you usually have to edit your theme to implement them. Also, line item properties do not affect price.   There are apps such as product customizer https://apps.shopify.com/product-customizer - but you'll have to play about with it to see if it fits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify allows a maximum of 3 variant options for any products and a total of 100 variants for the products. Any app that you can make or buy from the store has to implement the functionality inside these limits. Nevertheless, what you require can be implemented.

Shopify allows you to create a product customization description box for a product and the details in that box can be reflected in- cart page and also the invoice.

More details on it:

1. [Get customization information for Products](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products)
2. [Get more information on your cart page with cart attributes](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/customization/cart/get-more-information-with-cart-attributes)

You can use the combination of JavaScript and input multiple input fields to get the desired result without the use of any apps.

You might also be interested in utilizing [Product Metafields](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield) to some effect.